contourf, hatching not working on the last plot in a panel plot
Hatching don't work on the last plot in a panel plot.
The first and second plots are ploted fine, but the last plot doesn't work.
The "DJF_sig" variable is fine, I have attached a previously failed plot where the statistically significant areas are colored yellow. But I don't know why it doesn't work.
If anyone knows why, please let me know.
enter image description here
import netCDF4 as nc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon

file_path = './Diff_COBALT_DAILY_DJF_JJA.nc'
a_path='./signi_COBALT_DAILY_DJF_JJA.nc'
ds = nc.Dataset(file_path)
ds_a=nc.Dataset(a_path)
annual_sig=ds_a.variables['annual_sig2'][:]
DJF_sig=ds_a.variables['DJF_sig2'][:]
JJA_sig=ds_a.variables['JJA_sig2'][:]

annual = ds.variables['tos_diff_annual'][:]
DJF = ds.variables['tos_diff_DJF'][:]
JJA = ds.variables['tos_diff_JJA'][:]
yh=ds.variables['yh'][:]
xh=ds.variables['xh'][:]

an_sig_grid = np.where(annual_sig == 2)
an_sig_lon = xh[an_sig_grid[1]]
an_sig_lat = yh[an_sig_grid[0]]

DJF_sig_grid = np.where(DJF_sig == 2)
DJF_sig_lon = xh[DJF_sig_grid[1]]
DJF_sig_lat = yh[DJF_sig_grid[0]]

JJA_sig_grid = np.where(JJA_sig == 2)
JJA_sig_lon = xh[JJA_sig_grid[1]]
JJA_sig_lat = yh[JJA_sig_grid[0]]
xh, yh = np.meshgrid(xh, yh)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1, figsize=(12, 12), sharex=True, sharey=True)

def plot_with_hatching(ax, m, sst_data, sig_data):
    x, y = m(xh, yh)
    cs = m.pcolormesh(x, y, sst_data, shading='auto', cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5)
    sig_mask = np.ma.masked_where(sig_data != 2, sig_data)
    m.contourf(x, y, sig_mask, colors='none', hatches=['////'],extend='both', alpha=0)

    m.drawcoastlines()
    m.drawcountries()
    m.fillcontinents(color='black')
    m.drawparallels(np.arange(-90., 91., 30.), labels=[1,0,0,0])
    m.drawmeridians(np.arange(-180., 181., 60.), labels=[0,0,0,1])
    return cs
ax1 = axes[0]
m1 = Basemap(projection='cyl', lon_0=180, resolution='c', ax=ax1)
cs1=plot_with_hatching(ax1, m1, annual, annual_sig)
ax1.set_title('Annual')

ax2 = axes[1]
m2 = Basemap(projection='cyl', lon_0=180, resolution='c', ax=ax2)
cs2=plot_with_hatching(ax2, m2, JJA, JJA_sig)
ax2.set_title('JJA')

ax3 = axes[2]
m3 = Basemap(projection='cyl', lon_0=180, resolution='c', ax=ax3)
cs3=plot_with_hatching(ax3, m3, DJF, DJF_sig)
ax3.set_title('DJF')

cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.75, 0.15, 0.02, 0.7])
cbar = fig.colorbar(m3.pcolormesh(xh, yh, DJF, shading='auto', cmap='coolwarm', vmin=-0.5, vmax=0.5), cax=cbar_ax, ticks=np.arange(-0.5, 0.6, 0.1))

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.4)

plt.show()

enter image description here
If the "*_sig" variables have "2", these are statistically significant areas.

Are you sure that the areas in DJF are large enough and are not just too small for the hatch fill (i.e., a smaller than the width between hatch lines), and so are not just not be showing up. Could just try a single color fill and check this?

I additionally attached the link to the previously failed plot where the statistically significant areas are colored yellow. The regions of DJF are large enough. Please check the above edited context. Thanks for your comment.

As an experiment, could you try removing the two lines that add the colorbar?

Another thing to try might be explicitly setting the zorder of the contour plots to something large, e.g., in m.contourf(..., zorder=100) to make sure the hatching is always on top.
